# Evolution threads extra lines before signature

Tags: evolution

I am using html emails with *outlook style signature* and with every reply in a thread, the signatures for each email gets a few additional lines above it... any ideas?
(the issue is roughly like this)

```
# initial email
Hello world,

-- # <- signature starts here
from a.
# next reply
Hello back,

--
from b.
...
Hello world



-- # <- additional lines above signature.
from a.
```

etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the signature dashes altogether and, if you want, insert them manually into your signature.

You will need a dconf editor, either [the graphical one](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) or this:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
```

Now you can change the setting:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/evolution/mail/composer-no-signature-delim true
```

Source: https://geekphreek.com/remove-the-signature-dashes-from-evolution/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have a feeling that this will fix my issue!, I will just give it some time and testing before marking your answer as the correct.

Comment: This fixes the issue while introducing another one... Now the signature is plastered right after the message body no matter how many times I press `ENTER`...

Comment: Make a few lines above your signature (in the signature editor) and put a non-breakable space there (right Alt + space).

Comment: Thanks for your great help!

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working on Evolution 3.38.1 for me.

Comment: Works fine for me on Arch with the latest updates (Evolution 3.38.1).