# How to remove hyphens in signature in evolution mail

Tags: evolution, mail

When we design our signature in evolution mail, 2 dashes are automatically added before the signature, like this:

```
--
regards
fram
```

How can we remove those two hyphens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evolution threads extra lines before signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165728/evolution-threads-extra-lines-before-signature)

Comment: oh I'm sorry,
it was exactly that.
sorry.

Comment: Your question title is much clearer than the other one!